# How to work around the issue that I can't access some iStore apps of a different country?

Tags: apple-id, internationalization, apple-store

My family is spread across the world and I live and work in a different country than my native one.

My iPhone and Apple ID are registered to my country of residence.

On a few occasions, recently, I tried buying apps that were available only in my home country (I don't know exactly why) - but I got an error message saying I couldn't buy apps in that country with my current Apple ID.

First, I am not entirely sure I understand the rationale for such a restriction. Is it some kind of trade embargo?

Anyway, the main question is what can I do to circumvent this pointless restriction and still buy apps that are present only in my home country?

P.S.: I saw there were a few similar questions, but I am addressing specifically the ability to buy/download the app and not just view it (I can already view it!).

Comment: This has always been a part of the app store. The only way around it that I know of is to create a separate appleID for the second country. This is a pain when updating apps though as you will need to switch appleIDs when doing it. As to understanding the rationale - if you or anyone else can ever explain Apple's rationale you could make a fortune on chat programmes!

Answer (score 1):

You can make an separate AppleID for the other country.  You can load things from multiple AppleID accounts onto your phone at the same time, but it can be a bit of a pain as it will leave you in the account you were last in and you may inadvertently get new items into a different account than you intended.  Updating can be a pain, as it will require you to switch back and forth.

But, you will be able to get the apps (or other items) that are only available in the other country.